# Cleaning the duplicate names which has certain extensions

Tags: r, regex, data-science, data-cleaning

In the data table the company name column, some companies are coming repeatedly with a different name, e.g. Apple, and Apple _Do not call. I want to consider only one instead.  How do I clean those data? The company name which is repeating has the same value for other fields

```
Company Name     Volume
Apple              150
Wallmart           190
Apple_Do Not Call  150
Sapient            450
Apple inc.         150
```

if you eyeball the data, the Apple company are coming repeatedly with different name. I want to consider 1 value only, i.e. Apple

Answer (score 0):

You can group_by on a different field that has the same values (Volume in this case) then use mutate to change the Company Name to the first value of each group_by group

```
dt %>% group_by(Volume) %>% mutate(Company_Name = first(Company_Name))
```

`dt` here would be your data.table